# Google oauth multiple redirect uris won't work

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-api

I have a node.js application using googleapis oauth.

My developer console is set up with two redirect uris: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0tWW.jpg

I can make the initial call to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth with the redirect_uri to be either /token or /update

After a successful callback, I attempt to exchange the code for the token with the following code:

```
var exchangeToken = function (params) {
  var post_data = querystring.stringify({
    code: params.code,
    client_id: credentials.client_id,
    client_secret: credentials.client_secret,
    redirect_uri: 'https://www.example.org/token', //this line won't work
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
  });

  var req = https.request({
    host: 'www.googleapis.com',
    path: '/oauth2/v3/token',
    method: 'POST',
    port: 443,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': post_data.length
    }
  }, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) { 
      console.log('BODY: ' + chunk); 
    }); 
  }); 

  req.write(post_data);
  req.end();
```

};

If I set the redirect_uri to be /token the call falls, returning

```
BODY: {
 "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
 "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

But if I change to /update it works. The initial request accepts both urls, but this one fails for /token.

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-check that what you sent earlier in the authorization request matches what you send in the request to the token endpoint. You can use either URL that you've configured in the API Console but it must be the same in both requests.

Comment: debugging for hours -> twice the same redirect uri is the key point. thx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure redirect_uri: 'https://www.example.org/token' is same configured on Google Client API with **'Authorized redirect URIs'** block.

In my case, it works...!!!